# C++ Windows DLL: Exception Handling in Different Function

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

This is more of a design suggestion I need. Below code is from a C++ dll that am working on and this dll is called by many client executables. **InputParams** is a pointer to client exe.

The dll calls functions in the client to get certain values and the client doesn't have any exception build into it. So i need to implement exception handling in dll code.

for e.g., in the line **input->getName**, if it returns a NULL pointer or if **status** == ERROR, then I need to throw exception and catch it in **GetNumbers** function.

```
void Metrics::GetNumbers(InputParams* input, OutputParams* output)
    {
        int i, x, k;
        int status = 0;
        char* mesg;

        try{
             const char* name = input->getName(&status, &mesg); //this returns a name string 
             //and status will contain whether success or failure and mesg will have any error 
             //messages.

             const char* age = input->getAge(&status, &mesg);

            //Many other similar calls to client

             vector <int> myVectorNumers* = input->getNumberArray(&status, &mesg);

             vector <int> myVectorInfos* = input->getInfoArray(&status, &mesg);

            //Many other similar calls to client;
           }
         catch (std::exception e&)
         {
             // TODO
         }
         catch (string msg)
         {
             // TODO
         }
```

I came up with a way of doing it. And this is the snippet of code.

```
string errorMsg = "";
const char* name = input->getName(&status, &mesg); 

if (name == NULL || status == ERROR) // ERROR == 0
{
   errorMsg = mesg;
   throw errorMsg;
}

const char* age = input->getAge(&status, &mesg);

if (age== NULL || status == ERROR)
{
   errorMsg = mesg;
   throw errorMsg;
}

//Same for other calls to client using **input** pointer
```

Now as you see, I have to duplicate almost the same code in every place were there should be an exception check.

What am looking for is?

```
    string errorMsg = "";
    const char* name = input->getName(&status, &mesg); 

    CheckException(name, status, mesg, &errorMsg); // this function should do the error check and then throw the exception. And that exception should be caught by catch block in **GetNumbers** function.

    const char* age = input->getAge(&status, &mesg);

    CheckException(age, status, mesg, &errorMsg);
```

I have no idea whether even this is possible.

So a dummy implementation of **CheckException** will look like......

```
std::exception CheckException (/*1st parameter needs to be template type*/T* var, int status, string mesg, string *errorMsg)
{

    if (var == NULL || status == ERROR)
    {
        errorMsg = mesg;
        return /*TODO*/;  //Not sure how to return a throw
    }
}
```

1st of all, is this possible? Or is there a better way of doing this?

If you can provide me some sample code, that will be great!

Comment: This makes no sense. If client does not have exceptions then client code can not possibly return a valid pointer to `vector <int>` object. If it uses error codes to report errors then it would be a waste of resources to throw exceptions and catch them later in the same function instead of inspecting return code and immediately handling the error. If you want to throw exception from that `CheckException` function then you can just write `throw errorMsg;`.

Comment: @VTT = let's leave client out and just talk about handling exception inside the DLL. All i want is a separate function with one template argument to process the other arguments in a IF condition. This will all be within the DLL code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exceptions are not allowed to pass over the DLL boundary into the calling executable. The caller is not guaranteed to know how to handle an exception properly, especially in regards to cleanup, even if the executable and DLL are compiled with the same compiler.  Or, the caller may not even understand what an exception is at all, if the executable and DLL are compiled in different languages.

If you need to convey error information to the caller, you must do so using a return value, an output parameter, a separate function call, etc.  Things that are more-or-less universally supported across compilers/languages.

DO NOT throw exceptions over the DLL boundary into the caller!

**UPDATE**

You are already catching `std::exception&` in `GetNumbers()` (though, it really should be `const std::exception &` instead), so simply have `CheckException()` actually `throw` a `std::exception` object, don't try to `return` it, eg:

```
template<typename T>
void CheckException (const T *var, int status, const string &mesg)
{
    if (var == NULL || status == ERROR) {
        // or make a custom class derived from std::exception, if you want...
        throw std::runtime_error(mesg);
   }
}

...

try
{
    const char* name = input->getName(&status, &mesg); 
    CheckException(name, status, mesg);

    const char* age = input->getAge(&status, &mesg);
    CheckException(age, status, mesg);

    // Many other similar calls to client...

    vector<int> *myVectorNumers = input->getNumberArray(&status, &mesg);
    CheckException(myVectorNumers, status, mesg);

    vector<int> *myVectorInfos = input->getInfoArray(&status, &mesg);
    CheckException(myVectorInfos, status, mesg);

    // Many other similar calls to client...
}
catch (const std::exception e&)
{
    // TODO
}
```

Comment: This answer is rather weird. Most of dlls with C++ interface throw exceptions across dll boundaries, including usual standard library and boost. While use of C++ interfaces from other languages is rather uncommon. At the same time it seems that OP actually wants to throw and catch exceptions without leaving the function.

Comment: @VTT see [Exception Boundaries](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2014/01/16/exception-boundaries/) on MSDN.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau - I don't need to throw any exception across boundaries. Am talking about just handling this inside the DLL in a separate function.

Comment: @Kris ok, so what is the problem exactly? As long as you don't cross the DLL boundary, it is safe to throw yourself exceptions all you want. And you can certainly wrap common error checking code into helper functions to make life easier. So, where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau - Am basically stuck at writing the CheckException(....) function. How to write the 1st argument as Template and then how to throw the exception from inside that function are the 2 things i need help with? So basically, when the CheckException throws the exception, it needs to be caught in the GetNumbers function. Any chance you can write a sample CheckException function for me?